# Automated traversal, C#

Tags: c#

I'm in a need of doing the following:

1. Get parameter of type T and set it as current.
2. Check, whether (current).Parent exists and is of type A and if so, go there.
3. Check, whether (current).Owner exists and is of type B and if so, go there.
4. Check, whether (current).Whatever exists and is of type C and if so, go there.
5. Return (current).

This is an equivalent of

```
C c = ((param).Parent as A).Owner as B).Whatever as C;
```

with some security to check if any of the "steps" is null.

The problem is that I want to traverse through completely different types and by completely different properties. I need to do so in a few different places of my structure. Can this be automated in some way - maybe using lambdas, dynamics, some kind of generic classes? I'm thinking of something like:

```
C c = Util.Traverse<C>(someObj, new[]
{
    new Step { Path = p => p.Parent, ExpectedType = typeof(A) },
    new Step { Path = p => p.Owner, ExpectedType = typeof(B) },
    new Step { Path = p => p.Whatever, ExpectedType = typeof(C) }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use this often and sometimes have to use custom values instead of null you could write extension method like this:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static U SafeCast<T, U>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, object>> memberExpression, U defaultValue)
        where T : class
        where U : class
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }

        var me = memberExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (me == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("memberExpression must be MemberExpression");
        }

        // TODO : Check for fields, not only properties
        var memberValue = obj.GetType().GetProperty(me.Member.Name).GetValue(obj) as U;
        if (memberValue != null)
        {
            return memberValue;
        }

        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

and use it in this way:

```
var someObj = new SomeObj();
var defB = new B();
var res = someObj.SafeCast(a => a.Parent, default(A)).SafeCast(a => a.Owner, defB).SafeCast(a => a.Whatever, default(C));
```

Comment: Note, that I used all of your solutions to construct mine, but I couldn't mark all of them as answered. Thus, I choose the one, who had the least points at the moment. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

null-propagating expressions (i.e. where instead of a NRE, it evaluates as `null`) is something that has been informally kicked around a few times, but it simply isn't a feature that currently exists in C#.

There isn't a nice way to write this. The "ugly single statement" version would be:

```
A a;
B b;
C c;
// ...
return (a = param.Parent as A) == null ? null :
       (b = a.Owner as B) == null ? null :
       (c = b.Whatever as C) == null ? null :
       // ...
       c.FinalThing;
```

Personally, I'd just break it into lots of parts (probably in a helper method):

```
A a = param.Parent as A;
if(a==null) return null;
B b = a.Owner as B;
if(b==null) return null;
C c = b.Whatever as C;
if(c==null) return null;
// ...
return c.FinalThing;
```

Comment: Another interesting approach is the "maybe monad". See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109026/Chained-null-checks-and-the-Maybe-monad

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this using lambdas e.g.

```
Func<T, A> step1 = p => (p.Parent != null && p.Parent is A) ? p.Parent as A : null;
Func<A, B> step2 = p => (p.Owner != null && p.Owner is B) ? p.Owner as B : null;
Func<B, C> step3 = p => (p.Whatever != null && p.Whatever is C) ? p.Whatever as C : null;
...
A a = step1(someObj) != null;
B b;
C c;
if (a != null)
    b = step2(a);
if (b != null)
    c = step3(b);
return c;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
public static void CastAndContinue<T>(object toCast, Action<T> nextStep)
{
  if (toCast is T)
    nextStep((T)toCast);
}
```

Invoked as:

```
//(param).Parent as A).Owner as B).Whatever as C
finalThing localResult = null;
CastAndContinue<A>(param.Parent, 
    p => CastAndContinue<B>(p.Owner, 
    x => CastAndContinue<C>(x.Whatever, z=> finalThing = z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your guidance, I wrote two different solutions:

### Using dynamic and lambdas:

```
public struct Step {

    public Func<dynamic, dynamic> Path;
    public Type ExpectedType;
}

public static class StructureHelper {

    public static T Traverse<T>(dynamic obj, Step[] steps) {

        dynamic current = obj;
        for (int i = 0; i < steps.Length; i++) {

            if (current == null)
                return default(T);

            dynamic next = steps[i].Path(current);
            if (next.GetType() != steps[i].ExpectedType)
                return default(T);

            current = next;
        }

        if (current.GetType() == typeof(T))
            return (T)current;
        else
            return default(T);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
C c = StructureHelper.Traverse<C>(obj,
    new []
    {
        new Step { Path = p => p.Owner, ExpectedType = typeof(A) },
        new Step { Path = p => p.Parent, ExpectedType = typeof(B) },
        new Step { Path = p => p.Whatever, ExpectedType = typeof(C) }
    });
```

### Using lambdas and class helpers

```
public static U Traverse<T, U>(this T obj, Func<T, U> Step) 
    where T : class
    where U : class {

    if (obj == null)
        return null;

    U result = Step(obj);
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
C c = obj.Traverse(p => p.Parent as A)
    .Traverse(p => p.Owner as B)
    .Traverse(p => p.Whatever as C);
```